# row number without using the ROW_NUMBER window function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, row-number

Suppose you have a table with non-unique values such as this:

```
CREATE TABLE accounts ( fname VARCHAR(20), lname VARCHAR(20)) 
GO 

INSERT accounts VALUES ('Fred', 'Flintstone') 
INSERT accounts VALUES ('Fred', 'Flintstone') 
INSERT accounts VALUES ('Fred', 'Flintstone') 

SELECT * FROM accounts 
GO
```

Now using a ROW_NUMBER function, you can get a unique incrementing row number.

```
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by (select null)) as rn
from accounts
```

But how do we this without using a ROW_NUMBER function. I tried giving each row a unique ID using NEWID() and then counting the rows as given below but it did not work as it gives me a non-unique number which does not start with 1.
Note that I do not want to alter the table to add a new column.

```
;with cte as
(select *
from accounts as e
cross apply (select newid()) as a(id)
)
select *, (select count(*)+1 from cte as c1 where c.id > c1.id) as rn
from cte as c
order by rn
```

SQL Fiddle for toying around is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c270f/3/0

Comment: Fortunately, we have `row_number()`.

Comment: yeah. What's wrong with `row_number()`? It's the best thing invented for this thing.

Comment: What is wrong with row_number()?  It has been around since SQL 2005.  You want to use a cursor?

Comment: Nothing wrong. But trying to understand set based solution/pattern that will get me the answer without using Window function, cursors, etc. Kind of what you would do before window function were introduced. Anyway, I still don't understand why using NEWID() did not work.

Comment: @Paparazzi: window functions have been defined in SQL:2003, there never was a "SQL 2005" standard.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_SQL_Server

Comment: @Paparazzi https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2003 there was no "SQL 2005", the next version of the standard was "SQL 2006" ("SQL" is standard not a product name)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Tell WIKI they have conflicting information

Comment: @Paparazzi: they don't have conflicting information. You don't seem to undertand that "SQL" and "SQL Server" are two different things

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No words

Comment: Here's an old reference https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/186133/how-to-dynamically-number-rows-in-a-select-transact-sql-statement

Comment: @P.Salmon i had looked at that but won't work as the the row data is identical in my case. You have to add something unique to each row which can support ordering( i tried NEWID() for ordering). If I do use NEWID() for each row, I have to store the result to a #temp table and then work of it(the result of 'cte' in the code i have posted can be saved to #temp). It works but I am looking for a more elegant solution bypassing temp tables. Maybe I am asking too much.

Comment: Yes and duplicates are mentioned specifically in the drawbacks section, so I doubt if there was an elegant solution prior to 2005.

Answer (score 2):

The following demonstrates why your code fails, but does not provide an alternative to `Row_Number()`.

A column, `TopId`, is added to the final `select` that should get the minimum value generated by `NewId()` and report it in every row. Instead, a new value is generated for each row.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Samples as Table ( FName VarChar(20), LName VarChar(20) );
insert into @Samples ( FName, LName ) values
  ( 'Fred', 'Flintstone' ), ( 'Fred', 'Flintstone' ), ( 'Fred', 'Flintstone' );
select * from @Samples;

-- Cross apply   NewId()   in a CTE.
;with cte as
  ( select *
      from @Samples as S
    cross apply ( select NewId() ) as Ph( Id ) )
  select *, ( select count(*) from cte as c1 where c1.Id >= c.Id ) as RN,
    -- The following column should output the minimum   Id   value from the table for every row.
    --   Instead, it generates a new unique identifier for each row.
    ( select top 1 id from cte order by id ) as TopId
    from cte as c
    order by RN;
```

The execution plan shows that the CTE is treated as a view that is being evaluated repeatedly, thus generating conflicting `Id` values.

Comment: That explains it!

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
SELECT 
  src.*, 
  SUM(DummyVal) OVER(ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS RowId
FROM (
  SELECT a.*, 1 AS DummyVal
  FROM MyTable a
) src
```

It's still a window function, though, not sure if that matters.

[Fiddle me this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/052c0/2)

Comment: This approach is useful when you want to number rows according to the order by clause of the query. Otherwise you have to write the same order by clause inside "row_number over(..)".

Answer (score 0):

You can create an **function** yourself to compute the row_number,

In this example, I had to calculate an index for a lesson within a course.

Window Function version:

```
 SELECT *,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY courseId) AS row_num FROM lessons;
```

I created helper-function, to compute the row_number without window function:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION getRowNumber (lessonId int, courseId int) 
RETURNS int
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE count int;
select count(l2.id) into count  from lessons l2 where l2.courseId=courseId
and l2.id<=lessonId;
RETURN count;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

so, the final query is:

```
 SELECT l.*,  getRowNumber(l.id,l.courseId) as row_num  FROM lessons l;
```

got the same result as the first query!

Answer (score -2):

MySQL:

```
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, a.* 
FROM accounts a,(SELECT @rownum := 0) r;
```

In ORACLE it would simply be

```
SELECT ROWNUM, a.*
FROM accounts a;
```

Both without window

Comment: OP specifically put `sql-server` tag on the question.  What's the purpose of giving answer on other dbms???

Comment: it was not there in the beginning as far as I recall

Comment: My initial tags were 'T-SQL' and 'sql' as I was looking for either a standard sql set based answer or specific to sql server. I changed them to 'T-SQL' and 'sql server' to avoid confusion.